# How to print and see value of string in logtag android

Tags: java, android

I have a spinner and I want to see if its value chosen by the user is the appropriate one.How can I print this in log tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not logtag its Log Cat.And you can see your value like this
Log.i("log_tag", "anything  here" + yourstringvalue);

Answer (score 0):

I guess you meant `Logcat`. To print your values in the `Logcat`, you can use the [`Log`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) utility which Android provides. You can use the various levels of logging depending your needs.

**E.g:-**

```
Log.v("MyTag", "MyValue=" + myValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the `Log` API's for checking the output. Read more about [Log's here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html)

The available methods for a Log are: Log.v() Log.d() Log.i() Log.w() and Log.e()

For example, to *Log* a `String`, as an INFO log,

```
Log.i("SOME TAG", YOUR_STRING_INSTANCE);
```

This can be set to a trigger such as an `OnClickListener()`, or in an `AsyncTask` or in the `onCreate()`, etc.